# In MATLAB: How to multiply a symbolic variable (string) and a vector of floats?

Tags: matlab, octave, symbolic-math

I just started working with MATLAB and Octave. As I am new to the syntax, I am not very sure of my possibilities to work around problems. Now, I came across this warning:

*'warning: passing floating-point values to sym is dangerous, see "help sym" '*

when I tried to multiply a symbolic variable **t (sym)** with a vector of floats [sin(0.1), cos(0.1), -sin(0.1)].

The result I would wish for, in order to be able to keep calculating, should look like [0.09983*t, 0.995*t,-0.09983*t].

How can I obtain this?
Thanks!

Comment: This works without errors or warnings in MATLAB R2016b. What are you trying to run it in?

Comment: @gnovice I dont always get access to a MATLAB license and trying to work it out in Octave 4.2.1

Comment: Floating point math and symbolic math are very different and indeed one should be careful combining. When you multiply a symbolic variable with a numeric array, the result is symbolic, but the numeric array had to be converted somehow and this conversion can be ill-defined (e.g., symbolic "0.1" is not strictly equal to double precision "0.1" – see [this](http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/)). I suggest reading the help for `sym` carefully and also reading about variable precision arithmetic (`vpa`).

Comment: To echo the last comment: Avoid `sym`, unless you *specifically* are looking for that.

Comment: [This](http://octave-online.net/#cmd=syms%20t%3Bt*%20%5Bsin(0.1)%2C%20cos(0.1)%2C%20-sin(0.1)%5D) is a working example.